# polymorphism in java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

Is Interfaces in Java, a kind of 
polymorphism?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymorphism and Interfaces in Java (can polymorphism be used to implement interfaces...why?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423125/polymorphism-and-interfaces-in-java-can-polymorphism-be-used-to-implement-interf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Interfaces in Java are a construct to get polymorphism ( subtype polymorphism ) working in Java, but they are not a "kind" of polymorphism.

In polymorphism happens when two objects respond to the same message ( method call )  in different way ( hence poly -> many, morphism -> way or shape : polymorphism -> many ways). In Java to be able to send the same message to two different objects you have to either inherit the same parent, or implement the same interface.

Comment: strictly speaking, two objects don't need to have to have a common interface or parent/ancestor-class to respond to the same message. But having a common interface or parent, ensure they do. (and the way they react need not be different)

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, yes, but polymorphism usually refers to an objects ability to have different behaviors than that of it's parent class. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Using an interface among multiple classes ensures that all subclasses have to implement those methods, and thus the objects could be stored in an instance of  the superclass to allow for dynamic programming.

Read the link for a better example.

Answer (score 1):

No
Polymorphism means multiple forms.
Interface is a construct in Java for declaring static fields and declaring methods which will be implemented in classes implementing the Interface using keyword implement. 
Interfaces are not "a kind of" Polymorphism rather we use interfaces to get Polymorphism in Java.
This does not means that to get Polymorphism in Java we necessarily need Interfaces. Polymorphism can also be implemented using abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, interface is not polymorphism, they construct polymorphism. interface means when child class extends/ inherit parent class. polymorphism means, when parent class have different child sub-class,

```
parent p = new child1();
         = new child2();
         = new child3();
```

then the different child class object assigned to the same parent class reference known as polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. Long answer: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)