# Interface as a parameter

Tags: java, interface

I was going through this software library for semantic specs in java.

This particular code for implementing the DivRank has a method that takes a parameter called SparseMatrix: http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/source/browse/branches/matrix-rank/src/edu/ucla/sspace/matrix/DivRank.java?spec=svn1277&r=1277

The documentation in the package says that SparseMatrix is an interface: 
http://airhead-research.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/1.7/edu/ucla/sspace/matrix/SparseMatrix.html

My aim is to inject the values I have in a double[][] into this parameter.

SparseMatrix implements another interface called Matrix that has setRow and setColumn functions. When I tried to use that with an object of the interface I made, I got NullPointException. I think it is because I haven't had an instance of the SparseMatrix interface.

I then realized, I had to use a class that implements that interface and pass that classes object. But the documentation does not show any simple class that suits my need.

Do I need to define a new class that implements this interface and also override the interfaces functions and use the object to pass my values?

Comment: Yes, you could implement SparseMatrix. As it seems you have a full matrix (`double[][]`) and not a sparse matrix, I doubt that there exists an implementation class of SparseMatrix with a `double[][]` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not looked in details but on the javadoc (your second link), there's a list called "All Known Implementing Classes". You could check them and I'm sure you will find one that is a concrete class (i.e. not an interface or an abstract class) and does what you need. For example the [SparseHashMatrix](http://airhead-research.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/1.7/edu/ucla/sspace/matrix/SparseHashMatrix.html) has a [`set(row, col, value)`](http://airhead-research.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/1.7/edu/ucla/sspace/matrix/SparseHashMatrix.html#set%28int,%20int,%20double%29) method that you could use to populate a matrix from your `double[][]` with a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the find. On that note, the function that retrieves the values, getRowVector() again should return a SparseDoubleVector, which is an interface. What can I collect the values in? An implementing class, SparseHashDoubeVector which I tried, is giving me an incompatible types error!

Comment: you can use it as is. `SparseDoubleVector vector = matrix.getRowVector(0);` and then you can use its methods without worrying about the implementation, for example: `double firstCell = vector.get(0);`

Comment: Thanks! Worked. But, why the difference? The object of an interface is sufficient to collect, but not sufficient to send.

Comment: If you don't understand why it's probably worth googling it or asking on SO as the answer won't fit in this comment box!

Comment: @rook this would be a starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423125/polymorphism-and-interfaces-in-java-can-polymorphism-be-used-to-implement-inter